How to Disable the Add Text Function in Excalidraw on Double Tap?
I've already posted this question on the GitHub discussion page for Excalidraw, but I haven't received any responses yet, so I'm hoping someone here on StackOverflow can help.
By default, Excalidraw allows users to add text by double-clicking or double-tapping. I want to disable this behavior.
I added the following JavaScript code to disable double-click and double-tap, and here's what the script looks like:

$(document).ready(function() {
    var checkExist = setInterval(function() {
        var lastTap = 0;
        
        if ($(".excalidraw__canvas").length) {
            // Disable double-click on desktop
            $(".excalidraw__canvas").dblclick(function(e) {
                console.log("Double-click detected on excalidraw__canvas");
                e.stopPropagation();
                
            });

            // Disable double-tap on mobile
            $(".excalidraw__canvas").on("touchstart", function(e) {
                var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
                var tapLength = currentTime - lastTap;

                if (tapLength < 300 && tapLength > 0) {
                    console.log("Double-tap detected on excalidraw__canvas");
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    return false;
                }

                lastTap = currentTime;
            });

            
            clearInterval(checkExist);
        }
    }, 100); 
});

Although the double-click functionality is successfully disabled, the double-tap still triggers the add text function when in mobile view.
My backend is in PHP, and I'm using the index.php file as a guide, which you can find in this GitHub discussion link.
how can I override or disbale the add text by using double tap?

try to prevent the default double click behavior after stopPropagation using e.preventDefault();

@SaifeddineBenSalem At first, I tried that with double-click, but the add text function is still being triggered. Using e.stopPropagation() disabled the double-click. However, with double-tap, neither e.preventDefault() nor e.stopPropagation() disables the add text function.

Enter this into the console browser.
(function () {
  function getReactFiber(dom) {
    for (let key in dom) {
      if (key.startsWith("__reactFiber$") || key.startsWith("__reactInternalInstance$")) {
        return dom[key];
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  function findAndOverrideHandleCanvasDoubleClick(excalidrawContainer, attempt = 1) {
    if (!excalidrawContainer || excalidrawContainer.__excalidraw_doubleClickHandler_overridden) return;

    const fiber = getReactFiber(excalidrawContainer);
    if (!fiber) {
      if (attempt > 10) {
        console.error('Не удалось найти React Fiber узел на контейнере Excalidraw после 10 попыток.');
        return;
      }
      console.warn(`React Fiber узел не найден на контейнере Excalidraw. Повторная попытка через 500мс (попытка ${attempt}/10)...`);
      requestAnimationFrame(() => findAndOverrideHandleCanvasDoubleClick(excalidrawContainer, attempt + 1));
      return;
    }

    let currentFiber = fiber;

    while (currentFiber) {
      const { type, stateNode } = currentFiber;
      if (stateNode && typeof stateNode === 'object' && 'handleCanvasDoubleClick' in stateNode) {
        const originalHandle = stateNode.handleCanvasDoubleClick.bind(stateNode);

        stateNode.handleCanvasDoubleClick = function (event) {
          if (isTextToolActive()) {
            originalHandle(event);
          } else {
            console.log('Двойной клик заблокирован: неактивен инструмент "Текст".');
          }
        };
        console.log('Метод handleCanvasDoubleClick успешно переопределен для Excalidraw контейнера:', excalidrawContainer);
        Object.defineProperty(excalidrawContainer, '__excalidraw_doubleClickHandler_overridden', {
          value: true,
          writable: false,
          configurable: false,
        });
        return;
      }
      currentFiber = currentFiber.return;
    }

    if (currentFiber === null) {
      if (attempt > 10) {
        console.error('Компонент Excalidraw не найден в дереве React Fiber после 10 попыток.');
        return;
      }
      console.warn(`Компонент Excalidraw не найден в дереве React Fiber. Повторная попытка через 500мс (попытка ${attempt}/10)...`);
      requestAnimationFrame(() => findAndOverrideHandleCanvasDoubleClick(excalidrawContainer, attempt + 1));
    }
  }

  function isTextToolActive() {
    const activeTool = document.querySelector('.excalidraw-tool-tool-text');
    if (activeTool) {
      const isActive = activeTool.classList.contains('excalidraw-tool-active');
      console.log(`Инструмент "Текст" активен: ${isActive}`);
      return isActive;
    }
    console.log('Инструмент "Текст" не активен.');
    return false;
  }

  function initializeOverrides() {
    const excalidrawSelectors = ['.excalidraw-container'];
    excalidrawSelectors.forEach(selector => {
      const excalidrawContainers = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
      excalidrawContainers.forEach(container => {
        console.log('Обработка контейнера:', container);
        findAndOverrideHandleCanvasDoubleClick(container);
      });
    });
  }

  initializeOverrides();

  const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
    for (let mutation of mutations) {
      if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
        mutation.addedNodes.forEach(node => {
          if (node.nodeType === 1) { // ELEMENT_NODE
            const excalidrawSelectors = ['.excalidraw-container'];
            excalidrawSelectors.forEach(selector => {
              if (node.matches(selector)) {
                console.log('Найден новый контейнер Excalidraw:', node);
                findAndOverrideHandleCanvasDoubleClick(node);
              }
              const nestedExcalidraw = node.querySelectorAll(selector);
              nestedExcalidraw.forEach(nestedNode => {
                console.log('Найден вложенный контейнер Excalidraw:', nestedNode);
                findAndOverrideHandleCanvasDoubleClick(nestedNode);
              });
            });
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });

  observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });

  console.log('Скрипт для отключения вставки текста при двойном клике в Excalidraw активирован.');
})();


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@geosakr Your code disabled the text insertion on double-tap, but it also disabled the add text function on the canvas. What I need is to disable only the add text feature on double-tap, while still allowing text to be added using the toolbar.

@バッカマル  I fixed that. You can check it out

@geosakr thank you for your code! I have checked it and its working well

@geosakr, I just realized that existing text cannot be edited by double-tapping. Is it possible to also override the script so that editing existing text can be done by double-tap?

@バッカマル I was only able to implement this behavior in the source code by modifying the handleCanvasDoubleClick method, adding new logic. I still lack knowledge on how to make it work as in the previous solution, without editing the source code and building the program.

@geosakr What if I don't use the CDN link for excalidraw.production.min.js and instead save a local version of the script with your updated code? Do you think this would work?

@バッカマル Unfortunately, due to the CORS(Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) policy, the browser will block attempts to upload a local script to a page opened from another domain .(excalidraw.com). Therefore, this solution will not work directly.

@geosakr What if I have my own domain and am not using the Excalidraw domain? I’ve just integrated Excalidraw in the browser on my own domain.

@バッカマル You can enhance the logic in the App.tsx file by locating the private handleCanvasDoubleClick method and replacing it with my updated version of this method. Additionally, you need to add the private shouldAllowTextEditing method immediately after the handleCanvasDoubleClick method. Here is the script

@geosakr Thank you for the script. It has been a great help!

@バッカマル You're welcome! I'm glad I could help.
